# Extract if string contains numbers pattern

Tags: sql, string, split, sql-like, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column in my dataset where I want to extract the numbers in a specific location **ONLY IF** the structure of the string contains `#-#-#`.

How would I write this in SQL (writing in snowflake currently)?

Example:

```
Column_A
abc-net-met-1234-12345-431-5968
abc-eme-ejt-emdn-1948-192
jen-mdk-ent-193-102-1029398
loe-ekd-12-49-nfm
```

I want my expected output to be:

```
Column_A                            Number1    Number2    Number3   Number4
abc-net-met-1234-12345-431-5968        1234      12345        431      5968
abc-eme-ejt-emdn-1948-192              NULL       NULL       NULL      NULL            
jen-mdk-ent-193-102-1029398             193        102    1029398      NULL
loe-ekd-12-49-nfm                      NULL       NULL       NULL      NULL
```

I think it would be something like this but having trouble:

```
CASE WHEN COLUMN_A LIKE '%#-#-#%' THEN SPLIT_PART(COLUMN_A, '-', 4) ELSE NULL END Number1
CASE WHEN COLUMN_A LIKE '%#-#-#%' THEN SPLIT_PART(COLUMN_A, '-', 5) ELSE NULL END Number2
CASE WHEN COLUMN_A LIKE '%#-#-#%' THEN SPLIT_PART(COLUMN_A, '-', 6) ELSE NULL END Number3
CASE WHEN COLUMN_A LIKE '%#-#-#%' THEN SPLIT_PART(COLUMN_A, '-', 7) ELSE NULL END Number4
```

Comment: Which type of SQL?

Comment: The Snowflake documentation is saying "ANSI"

Comment: So, you want the numbers if there are ATLEAST 3 numbers in sequence...regardless of the string count?  What happens if the numbers are separated by a string like A-B-1-2-Z-3?

Comment: then that doesn't work, needs to be like this: `#-#-#`

Comment: Since the number seqences start at different parts for different `Column_A`, you can't extract the numbers with the constants 4-7.

Comment: For those that do contain the 3 numbers in a row, it always starts at the 4th position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your `like` expression is too broad. You can narrow it with a regex match, like:

```
CASE 
    WHEN COLUMN_A RLIKE '.*(^|-)[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+($|-).*' 
    THEN SPLIT_PART(COLUMN_A, '-', 4) 
    ELSE NULL 
END Number1
```

The regexp matches on 3 consecutive groups of digits separated by dashes, and preceeded by a dash (or located at the beginning of the string), or followed by a dash (or located at the end of the string).

This can also be spelled:

```
CASE 
    WHEN COLUMN_A RLIKE '.*(^|-)\\d+-\\d+-\\d+($|-).*' 
    THEN SPLIT_PART(COLUMN_A, '-', 4) 
    ELSE NULL 
END Number1
```

Comment: No luck with this, I tried it on this specific string: `ABC-ACROBAT-OWL-23020365-255738062-451886974-121804749`

Comment: All of my values are capitalized, does that make a difference?

Comment: @nak5120: this string should match the regex. What do you get if you do something like: `SELECT CASE WHEN 'ABC-ACROBAT-OWL-23020365-255738062-451886974-121804749' RLIKE '^[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-\d+-' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`: 0 or 1?

Comment: I get 0 unfortunately

Comment: OK. What if you use this regex instead: `'^[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+-'`?

Comment: same thing, I get a 0

Comment: Also I am looking for 3 numbers connected by a dash, not alphabetic characters. But I think once the foundation is figured out then I could just do something like `^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]`

Comment: @nak5120: OK let's change the approach then. Maybe something like `'\b\d+-\d+-\d+\b'`? Does it match your string?

Comment: nope, this is what I did: `SELECT CASE WHEN 'ABC-ACROBAT-OWL-23020365-255738062-451886974-121804749' RLIKE '\b\d+-\d+-\d+\b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` Result = 0

Comment: `'(^|-)\d+-\d+-\d+($|-)'`?

Comment: no luck, tried this: `SELECT CASE WHEN 'ABC-ACROBAT-OWL-23020365-255738062-451886974-121804749' RLIKE '(^|-)\d+-\d+-\d+($|-)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: The data type for the string is: VARCHAR(16777216)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202112/discussion-between-gmb-and-nak5120).

Comment: Please remember that the special character \ in Snowflake regexps has to be escaped for general string parsing, so that the regexp string to match a digit is '\\d'

Comment: @HansHenrikEriksen: ah yes... now that you say it it seems so obvious. I understand now why some of my attempts were failing. Thanks for the reminder, I updated my answer accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the current "correct answer" is marked as such, because although it selects the correct lines, it doesn't extract the result in any particularly useful way.

The following query provides the correct answer by first extracting a substring with at least 3 consecutive numbers, and then extracting the nth number from that substring of 3+ numbers:

```
WITH TEST_TAB AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('abc-net-met-1234-12345-431-5968'), ('abc-eme-ejt-emdn-1948-192'),
    ('jen-mdk-ent-193-102-1029398'),     ('loe-ekd-12-49-nfm')
  ) T(COLUMN_A))
SELECT COLUMN_A,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('-'||COLUMN_A||'-', '(-\\d+){3,}-'), '\\d+', 2, 1) Number1,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('-'||COLUMN_A||'-', '(-\\d+){3,}-'), '\\d+', 2, 2) Number2,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('-'||COLUMN_A||'-', '(-\\d+){3,}-'), '\\d+', 2, 3) Number3,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('-'||COLUMN_A||'-', '(-\\d+){3,}-'), '\\d+', 2, 4) Number4
FROM TEST_TAB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Snowflake on-hand, but something like this should work:
Here is the suggested approach:  Split the string into a table, enumerate the numbers, and then use conditional aggregation.

I don't have Snowflake on hand to test, but something like this:

```
select column_a,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as number_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as number_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as number_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then value end) as number_4
from (select t.column_a, s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when s.value rlike '^[0-9]+$'
                                                   then 1 else 0
                                              end)
                                              order by s.index
                               ) as seqnum
      from t cross join lateral
           split_to_table(t.column_a, '-') s
     ) t
group by column_a;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but I am looking to avoid any joins. Something like the previous answer would be perfect because I have other rules occurring besides this

Comment: @nak5120 . . . This does what you want and work generally for all columns.  It seems like the answer to the question you asked.

Comment: I've run the code above, and it doesn't seem to produce the correct result.  For one, all the 1st text parts (abc, abc, jen, loe) of `COLUMN_A` get reported as numbers.  There is also no code to assure there are at least 3 consecutive numbers.